# Android AdView NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, admob

I'm a Beginner in Android Development. I just released an app but found some glitches, so I thought of correcting those glitches by creating a new Android project with the same package name as that of the released app. But once I finished with the update app, This app is not running on phone(debugging). Says "Unfortunately thisApp has Stopped." And also im trying to incorporate adMob this time.

Please help me because I have to publish this asap.

Here's the Logcat once the app crashes :

```
08-11 18:14:31.063: E/dalvikvm(15877): Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth.BlueActivity.initAdView
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth.BlueActivity.initAdView(BlueActivity.java:107)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth.BlueActivity.onCreate(BlueActivity.java:40)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-11 18:14:31.254: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the XML of my admob placement. I just followed [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Advertisements-to-Your-Android-Applications-Using-Admob) to Add admob.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/easyb"
tools:context=".BlueActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adviewPlaceholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

//Other elements
```

And I've put this in my manifest file >

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >

    </activity>
```

And this in my Activity onCreate method >

```
private AdView ad;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue);

    initAdView();
//Other elements
protected void initAdView() {

    ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "a15204b9eb97566");

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adviewPlaceholder);

    ll.addView(ad);

    ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}

protected void destroyAdView() {
    if(ad != null) ad.destroy();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {    
    // destroy the ad when the activity is destroyed
    destroyAdView();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this line in the error message:

> 08-11 02:28:56.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27461):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth/com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth.BlueActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
>   inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

There is a problem with your AdView that causes the app to crash.

Could you please post your .xml layout file as well as the Activity.

**UPDATE:**

In order to make this a bit more clear. I never define the AdView in .xml. I simply create a Layout inside my layout .xml file that has no children, and via code I add the AdView to it. It looks like this:

```
      private AdView ad;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

          initAdView();

          // other code...
      }

       protected void initAdView() {

            ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "MY_AD_UNIT_ID");

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adviewPlaceholder);

            ll.addView(ad);

            ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        }

        protected void destroyAdView() {
            if(ad != null) ad.destroy();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {    
            // destroy the ad when the activity is destroyed
            destroyAdView();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
```

And the Layout yourlayout.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent >

    <!-- lots of other layout stuff here -->


    <!-- make the adview be on the bottom of the screen -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adviewPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have posted the xml and manifest file where admob is present. Please take a look . Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong creating the AdView in XML, but just in case I also prefer to create it in code. Especially if you have different flavors of the app, or IAB products to remove advertisement.

Comment: Of course there is nothing wrong with creating it in .xml but I also prefer code since I kinda feel like having more control over things :)
@Abhijit: please try my above suggestion and see if it works then.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I did try it but it only reduced my number of errors. You can have a look at my question now. I have edited as you said, both in the .xml and .java files. And I'm not getting less errors.

Comment: Please assist me with this, because I'm not able to get this right at all. Thanks

Comment: Could you please name all the error messages you get. Also make sure that your other elements are below the adviewPlaceholder. Otherwise they will hide the AdView.

Comment: I have named all the errors im getting in the edited question above. And yes, I have made sure all the elements are below the adviewPlaceholder

Comment: have you added the needed .jar file that supports the AdMob SDK to your project?

Comment: yea i have. in the referenced library folder

Comment: could you tell us what line in your code above is line 107? please highlight it ore something.

Comment: I have added a few Button in the end of onCreate(). closed and started with the protected void initAdView() method.

Comment: I finally got the Answer. Here's the solution> stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: my bad :D. Sorry for causing the inconvenience guys. I very much appreciate your time. Thanks a ton

Comment: @Abhijit I see you found your answer. Of course, I asked you the same thing as a comment in the other answer: *"Do you put the AdMob jar in libs or in a custom libraries folder?"* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your adView is causing the crash.  How are you implementing it?  Have you included all the permissions required in the manifest?

The ClassNotFound exception indicates that somewhere your admob library isn't connecting to your XML.  There are a few things that can cause this, but the most likely are either that it's not declared in the manifest:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:debuggable="true">
  <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="yourActivity">
       .....
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"   <----- this line
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
 </application>
```

or that it's not declared at the top of your XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"   <----- this line
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Try those out, and if they don't do the trick check out Google's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android) and [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android)

Comment: I have posted the xml and manifest file where admob is present. Please take a look . I have added the INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in the manifest.

Comment: How are you building the app? If you're working with the command line (e.g., Gradle or ANT), it may happen that your IDE project may be configured with different module/library settings, leaving you with valid classes in IDE, but missing ones after the building process. Do you put the AdMob jar in libs or in a custom libraries folder?

Comment: I have put the above codes earlier. still shows the same errors

Comment: And I'm using Eclipse to develop this app. the admob jar file is present in the referenced Library folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code or your XML AFAICT. The error clearly states:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdView'
```

It would seem that your deployed app does not contain the Admob library. You need to work out why. Check your build tool/environment.