# Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: android, jar, admob, runtime-error

Alright, so I've been going through the tutorial in AdMob, and after trying to compile, I was first faced this annoying run time error.
 I've been trying for the past few hours to fix it and trying some solutions, such as putting the JAR file in the libs folder and so on.. but I keep getting this error.
I will be very thankfull if someone could look into my problem and figure out what I am probably doing wrong.

First, my logcat: http://pastebin.com/4tRh31Xh

Here's how it looks:

[image]
[image]

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name="org.holoeverywhere.app.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/safecam_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.inturnex.safecam.MainActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
       <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you also post the code of your onCreate() method where you initialize the AdView?

Comment: @Phil I don't initialize any AdView via code, it's all through XML.

Comment: I see, well your import of the libary and the Manifest look ok, but I would suggest that you put all your files into the libs folder.
Have you considered trying it via code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166379/my-app-crashes-says-unfortunaly-stopped-android-please-assist/18166407#18166407

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your efforts helping me :) . I finally found out what was the problem. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, finally, I figured out what the problem is. I had to look a bit deeper in the logcat.

I use HoloEverywhere library, as you can see in the end of the logcat file, it says:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HoloEverywhere: PreferenceFramework not found

The solution: 
I had to import the HoloEverywhere Addons Preferences library into my project, and now it works like a charm.